# Decrease time transfer between sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, printf

I'm programming on CentOS with C. From the client I have to send 3,000,000 numbers to server, and in the server print each number in the shortest time possible. It takes 32 seconds now, but the time must be at most 20 seconds. Printing the 3,000,000 numbers in the server takes 16 seconds, so I suppose the time lost is because the trasference. Code fragment of my programs:

Server:

```
...
while(read(socket,&num,4)>0)
   printf("%i ",num);
...
```

Client:

```
...
for(i=1;i<=3000000,i++)
   write(clientSocket,&i,4);
...
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Profile, profile, profile.  In this case I can confidently predict that the majority of the time will be spent in `printf` and the remainder in the `read` and `write` calls, but don't take my word for it.  Speeding up binary-to-decimal conversion is hard, but assuming this is loopback or local ethernet, the data transfer time should be cut at least in half without much effort if you read and write 1024-byte blocks instead of one 4-byte integer at a time.

Comment: Write to and read from the socket in bigger chunks. Syscalls are expensive. See if this helps.

Comment: what type of socket you created? Udp or tcp?

Comment: Also, what is stdout pointing at in the server, some file?

Comment: @Richard If you don't have any restriction, can you try udp?

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody! I have solved this issue writing and reading in blocks of 1000 bytes, the time is now 17 seconds, which is even less than the limit of 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue writing and reading in blocks of 1000 bytes, the time is now 17 seconds, which is even less than the limit of 20 seconds. – Richard

Comment: The benefit of adding an answer is that maybe the question can achieve closure, but since only the OP can accept an answer, and the OP has not been seen for two years or so, the chances of anything beneficial happening are limited.